# Optimize Postgres TOP-n query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

Table with two columns (transaction_id, user_id), both with index. Approx 10M records in table.

transaction_id is unique

transaction_id count on user_id varies from very few to thousands.

What I need is to find the max(transaction_id), with respect to that the top25 (order by desc) transaction_id's on a given user must be ignored.

Eg a user_id with 21 transaction_id's will not be selected. A user_id with 47 transactions will return transaction 26.

I have tried several ways by using offset, limit etc, but they all seem to be to slow (very high cost).

Comment: `I have tried several ways` ... please post your queries so that we don't waste time redoing what may have already failed for you.  Also, sample data would be nice.  You could replace `25` with the number `3` if it means being able to show us meaningful data.

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: you want to order `transaction_id`, grouped by `user_id`, then ignore all results, but 26th row for each `user_id` - what do you expect to speed up?..

Comment: I thought of something like this:       select max(transaction_id),user_id from mytable group by user_id offset 25;        using offset to ignore first 25.. but that will then be for the total result.. I would like to use offset for each grouped user_id

Answer (score 0):

you have a window functions i.e.

```
select user_id, nth_value(transaction_id, 26) over (
  partition by user_id order by transaction_id
)
from your_table;
```

should be plenty